# format JSON with rails when key is a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-visualization

With rails, I'm trying to render this JSON:

```
             options:
               { seriesType: "bars",
                 series: {1: {type: "line"}},
                 width: 375, 
                 height: 240,
                 legend: 'none',
                 pointSize: 5,
                 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                 vAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 }
                }
```

I'm having problems with this line

```
                 series: {1: {type: "line"}},
```

and it seems that the reason is that the key is a number {1: ...

What's the way to render a Json with a number as a key?

Answer (score 0):

The object key in JSON format must be a string.  If you want to represent a numeric value, placed it in quotes:

```
series: {"1": {type: "line"}},
```

Comment: @FranJMartínez That would work as well if what you really intend to store there an array of values anyway.

Comment: My first tests has been things like series: {"1": {type: "line"}} but I get an error with rails

Answer (score 0):

I have found a half answer... I didn't find how to specify what column I want to change the style, but I can change every column one by one by this way:

```
series: [{type: "bars"}, {type: "line"}],
```

or better

```
series: [nil, {type: "line"}],
```

so it will use "bars" for column 0, and "line" for column 1.